# How to get latest version of DiG?

Tags: macos, dns, dig

After wanting to check some DNS records, I realized that my current version (9.8.3-P1) of `DiG`, that shipped with Mac OS X (El Capitan 10.11.6), does not support the RR type I need.

So now I am looking to get an up-to-date version that I can run on my system. Now my question is, where can I get the current version of the tool? I know that on most Linux distros it's shipped with the `dnsutils` package, but I have no idea about Mac OS X. If necessary, I am willing to compile it myself, but I haven't found the source files yet.

Comment: MacPorts has a dig-like tool called "drill", part of the "ldns" package: https://github.com/macports/macports-ports/blob/master/net/ldns/Portfile

Answer (score 14):

as `dig` is a part of `bind` package just install bind then you will be able to use `dig` on mac:-

```
   brew install bind
```

Answer (score 0):

dig is part of the BIND software suite. You can get the latest from the ISC.

Edited: https://www.isc.org/downloads/bind/

Comment: This would be more useful if you provided an actual link.

Comment: Links have a tendency to become invalid after awhile that a why I didn't include one but the freshest link to the isc.org software via ftp is http://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/

Comment: But can I install `dig` without installing the DNS server too?

Comment: @comfreak Just do not start it. `brew info bind` shows you more details